# How can I add a class attribute to all my forms widgets automatically in Django?

Tags: python, css, django, forms

I would like that every time I create a form with django the tag input includes a specific css class (form-control), to do this I have to write in form.py the following code, adding lines for each field:

```
class InsertItem(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['price'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Is there a way to force Django to include the css class that I need in every form, without having to write that things for each from and each line?

Comment: it would be much easier to do it with javascript if you want all of them to share the same class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a common base class that updates every field:

```
class StylishForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

and inherit from it:

```
class InsertItem(StylishForm):
   ...
```

Comment: I am learning now django/python, so I don't understand, isn't BaseForm a "default" class included in django? So you suggest to override BaseForm?

Comment: Call it whatever you like; I've updated the name. The point is that you inherit from that rather than the basic ModelForm.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) application to add class attribute.

1. [install](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks#installation) application
2. create `form` just `modelForm`

```
class InsertItem(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = modelName
```

3. use application in template code

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

`{% load widget_tweaks %}` : load application to use it

`{% render_field` : command
`field` : field name to add class
`class="form-control" %}` : attribute